# How to validate radio part?

Tags: html, jquery, validation, radio-button

I created the following form:

http://jsfiddle.net/baumdexterous/KKqbT/1/

```
    <!-- VALIDATION NOTIFICATION -->
    <div id="drawer">Please fill in the empty fields marked with  a <samp style="color:red">red</samp> border.</div>
    <!-- END VALIDATION NOTIFICATION -->


    <!-- FORM -->
    <form action="#">
      <div id="wizard">
        <div class="items">
          <div class="page">
              <ul>
                <li class="required">

                <!-- INPUT -->
                <label>Your Email:<br><input type="text" class="text" name="email"></label>

                <!-- SELECT DROPDOWN -->
                <label>Your City
                    <select name="city">
                        <option value="">-- please select --</option>
                        <option>Helsinki</option>
                        <option>Berlin</option>
                        <option>New York</option>
                    </select>
                </label>

                <!-- RADIO -->
                <label>What's the U.S. capital?<br>
                    <div class="qselections">
                        <input type="radio" value="a" name="question1">a) New York<br>
                        <input type="radio" value="b" name="question1">b) Washington DC<br>
                        <input type="radio" value="c" name="question1">c) Seattle<br>
                        <input type="radio" value="d" name="question1">d) Portland<br>
                    </div>
                </label>            
          </li>

          <li class="clearfix">
            <button type="button" class="next right">
                Proceed »
            </button>
          </li>

        </ul>

          </div> <!-- end page -->


        </div><!--items-->

      </div><!--wizard-->

    </form>
```

Here is the existing validation:

```
    $(function() {
      var root = $("#wizard").scrollable();

      // some variables that we need
    var api = root.scrollable(), drawer = $("#drawer");

    // validation logic is done inside the onBeforeSeek callback
    api.onBeforeSeek(function(event, i) {

    // we are going 1 step backwards so no need for validation
    if (api.getIndex() < i) {

                 // 1. get current page
                 var page = root.find(".page").eq(api.getIndex()),

             // 2. .. and all required fields inside the page
             inputs = page.find(".required :input").removeClass("error"),

             // 3. .. which are empty
             empty = inputs.filter(function() {
             return $(this).val().replace(/\s*/g, '') == '';
             });

                 // if there are empty fields, then
                 if (empty.length) {

             // slide down the drawer
             drawer.slideDown(function()  {

             // colored flash effect
             drawer.css("backgroundColor", "#229");
             setTimeout(function() { drawer.css("backgroundColor", "#fff"); }, 1000);
             });

             // add a CSS class name "error" for empty & required fields
             empty.addClass("error");

             // cancel seeking of the scrollable by returning false
             return false;

                 // everything is good
                 } else {

             // hide the drawer
             drawer.slideUp();
                 }

                     }

                     // update status bar
                     $("#status li").removeClass("active").eq(i).addClass("active");

                         });

                             // if tab is pressed on the next button seek to next page
    root.find("button.next").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {

    // seeks to next tab by executing our validation routine
    api.next();
    e.preventDefault();
    }
    });
                           });
```

I am able to validate the input part and select dropdown form elements just fine... but for some reason unable to validate the radio form element. Anyone knows what I need to do specifically to this code to make the radio validation work? Thank you.

Comment: You've shown no validation code whatsoever in your OP.  Also, please refrain from tag spam... the [tag:jquery-validate] plugin has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @Sparky I apologize for my lack of information in the original question. I went ahead and added the validation code and the jquery-validate part is now removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/7qD6F/ **OR** http://jsfiddle.net/4Shvw/ **OR** http://jsfiddle.net/7N8K9/

**Alertless version** http://jsfiddle.net/8tMbV/

Hope this will fit your need `:)`

I have treated the `input` radiobutton separately to make it clear for you!

**Code**

```
  $(function () {
      var root = $("#wizard").scrollable();
      var isRadioCheck = false;  //<======================New Var
      // some variables that we need
      var api = root.scrollable(),
          drawer = $("#drawer");

      // validation logic is done inside the onBeforeSeek callback
      api.onBeforeSeek(function (event, i) {

          // we are going 1 step backwards so no need for validation
          if (api.getIndex() < i || $('input[type=radio]').is(':checked')) {

              // 1. get current page
              var page = root.find(".page,.qselections").eq(api.getIndex()),

                  // 2. .. and all required fields inside the page
                  inputs = page.find(".required :input").removeClass("error"),

                  // 3. .. which are empty
                  empty = inputs.filter(function () {
                      isRadioCheck = $('input[type=radio]').is(':checked');
                      return $(this).val().replace(/\s*/g, '') == '';
                  });


              //    alert('Empty Value is bool : ' + empty.length + isRadioCheck);
              // if there are empty fields, then
              if (empty.length || !isRadioCheck) { //<======================Conditional Check

                  // slide down the drawer
                  drawer.slideDown(function () {

                      // colored flash effect
                      drawer.css("backgroundColor", "#229");
                      setTimeout(function () {
                          drawer.css("backgroundColor", "#fff");
                      }, 1000);
                  });

                  // add a CSS class name "error" for empty & required fields
                  empty.addClass("error");
                  $('.qselections').addClass("error");
                  // cancel seeking of the scrollable by returning false
                  return false;

                  // everything is good
              } else {

                  // hide the drawer
                  drawer.slideUp();
              }

          }

          // update status bar
          $("#status li").removeClass("active").eq(i).addClass("active");

      });

      // if tab is pressed on the next button seek to next page
      root.find("button.next").keydown(function (e) {
          if (e.keyCode == 9) {

              // seeks to next tab by executing our validation routine
              api.next();
              e.preventDefault();
          }
      });
  });
```

**Image** *working highlight*

[image]

Comment: You are just missing removing the `error` class from `.qselections` when a radio button is checked.

Comment: @Trevor Cheers bruvooo `:)~ **Done** here: http://jsfiddle.net/4Shvw/ +1 to you as well!

Comment: Thank you, I know it would not happen very often but what about the case where the radio button was the only thing checked and then they tried to proceed.  Wouldn't you want to only add the `error` class to `.qselections` if `isRadioCheck` was false and then clear it for the cases where the radio button is checked but the other fields are empty? :)

Comment: @Trevor Saweeet man here you go **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/7N8K9/ `:))` Good human!

Comment: Thanks I appreciate you making the changes, I like the way you did it!  So its looking great only one more thing.  Hit submit first. (all red) Then check a radio box. Hit submit again (radio box is still red)

Comment: Wow, you guys are amazing! Thank you so much. The only issue with your current modification however is that I see a browser pop up first... Is there a way to disable that? I just want the warning message at the top to appear.

Comment: @Trevor Cooleos, 1 hot changes, coming right away Homziee! `:)` No worries! Bro dont delete your cahgnes they are saweet!

Comment: @Ori I'm not sure what you mean by `browser pop up` What does the pop up say?

Comment: @Ori Do you mean the alert boxes?  Search for the `alert(` and comment them out.  They are there to help you see whats going on.

Comment: You are both seriously amazing. THANK YOU SO MUCH for taking the time to explain to me how everything works. I am so impressed by your detailed explanations and willingness to help. Last question: Do you have any idea how I can remove the blue background that appears on the warning notification at the top? It kinda flickers for a second and then disappears. Thanks again so much!!!

Comment: @Ori Change this line to `drawer.css("backgroundColor", "#fff");` instead of `drawer.css("backgroundColor", "#229");`

Comment: Brilliant! It worked. Thank you @Trevor. Sorry, one more thing – do you know how I can prevent the user from making another selection once one radio option has been selected? In other words, would be great if their radio selection gets locked. Thank you for everything!!

Comment: @Ori Sure, put this `$('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
          $('input[type=radio]').prop('disabled',true);    
      });` just inside your `$(function () {` code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify your code to handle `Radio inputs` which don't have values.  Here is a modification that I made with your filter function, hopefully it will be useful to you.

```
empty = inputs.filter(function() {
             if($(this).attr('type') == 'radio'){
                 if($(this).parent().hasClass('error'))
                      $(this).parent().removeClass('error');  
                 if(!$('input[name='+$(this).attr('name')+']').is(':checked'))
                 {
                   if(!$(this).parent().hasClass('error')){
                      $(this).parent().addClass('error');
                      return true;
                   }    
                 }
                 return false;
             }
             return $(this).val().replace(/\s*/g, '') == '';
});
```

**Update**

Tats answer and his `Alertless` fiddle covers everything and is easier to understand.

Comment: Here you go + 1, plz feel free to use my demo and stick one up man! `:)`